# cmd call in Wix

Tags: cmd, wix

I searched for some days and all what I found not worked. I want so call cmd in my WiX installer to install a service and a key.

The cmd call worked very well, but nothing happend. This means the service and the keys not be installed.

```
<CustomAction Id='CMDInstallService' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION' Execute='deferred' ExeCommand='[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /c &quot;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil.exe /DisplayName=[DISPLAYNAME] /ServiceName=[SERVICENAME] [INSTALLLOCATION][ProductName]\bin\PontefixSvc.exe&quot;' Return='ignore'/>
<CustomAction Id='CMDInstallKey' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION' Execute='deferred' ExeCommand='[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /c &quot; [INSTALLLOCATION][ProductName]\scripts\PontefixEncryptionTool.exe -install [ProductName] [INSTALLLOCATION][ProductName]\KeyContainer\keycontainer.pkxml del .\keycontainer.pkxml &quot;' Return='ignore' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>

  <Custom Action='CMDInstallService' Before='InstallFinalize'></Custom>
  <Custom Action='CMDInstallKey' Before='InstallFinalize'></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Perhaps I found out the mistake. Do somebody know, how to implement this: " in wix / xml code, if this is also there? I mean, how I can write: "Hello, my name is "Susi"" and it woks like it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run commands i would recommend you use Quite Execution CA. You will find examples in Wix documentation: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html and what you want is Deferred Execution, i.e. two custom actions for one execution.

Also i notice you are installing a Service in first CA through cmd, why wouldn't you use Wix ServiceInstall instad? (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html)

Comment: I am not sure why this was voted down but using ServiceInstall is the way to install service if you are using a WixInstaller.